# How can I exchange EUR to USD on Interactive Brokers without going through FXCONV?

Tags: foreign-exchange, interactive-brokers

I'm looking at this Interactive Brokers account:

[image]

The cash position is 77,535.00 EUR. Interactive Brokers say it's worth 84,755.45 USD. xe.com [agrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvBqS.png) with that estimate. However, converting 77,535.00 EUR to USD via FXCONV (where Interactive Brokers is routing such orders by default) only brings 84,565.42 USD, which is a 190.03 USD less than 84,755.45 USD. Therefore, I don't thing going through FXCONV is optimal.

How can I exchange EUR to USD on Interactive Brokers without going through a FXCONV?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better addressed directly to product support.

Comment: @keshlam that's not a reason to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One can use the Interactive Brokers Trader Workstation (TWS) to [choose the destination](https://www.reddit.com/r/interactivebrokers/comments/12du8ea/why_is_the_usd_value_of_cash_position_200_usd/jf834s7/):

[image]